# Android SMS/MMS not getting deleted

Tags: sms, mms, delete

I've tried many different things to delete my SMS/MMS messages but nothing has worked. Things I've tried so far

History Eraser https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.eraser&hl=en_US

tried deleting them manually one by one.

and I tried creating an Android app and getting the following line to execute

```
mContext.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null);
```

But no method was successful. Are there any other options worth a try? I don't want to do a factory reset or root my phone.